# I can't seem to figure out why this query gives me error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Im on the wamp server trying to make a little posting system for my site.

My PHP to post is:

```
$c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("postes");
$t = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$ts = time();
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `postes`(`title`, `text`, `timestamp`) VALUES (`$t`,`$body`,`$ts`)")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I'm using Ajax to send:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send').click(function () {
        var n = $('#title').val(),
            e = $('#body').val();
        $.post('post.php', {
            title: n,
            body: e
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data)
        });
    });
});
```

Whatever I enter in the title field on my site I get an error. It says: "Unknown column '{text}' in 'field list'"

I'm not even entering the title in the column section of the sql though, so I dont get this. Also, i'm new to PHP and Mysql

Comment: In your "INSERT" statement, you include the column name "text" in the list of column values to be provided. If the table "postes" has no column called "text", you should not include that name.

Comment: @Pointy the `text` comes as a submitted value, I guess. So it looks like @Kolink's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724948/i-cant-seem-to-figure-out-why-this-query-gives-me-error/11724986#11724986) is correct

Answer (score 6):

Values must be wrapped in quotes, not backticks. Backticks are for names of databases, tables, fields, indexes and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that such field does not exist in table `postes`

Answer (score 2):

The query

```
INSERT INTO `postes`(`title`, `text`, `timestamp`) VALUES (`$t`,`$body`,`$ts`)
```

Requires that your *postes* table contains columns named *title*, *text* and *timestamp*. Make sure these columns exist in the table definition.